# Can't open IntelliJ after editing vmoptions

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I changed the vmoptions in my IntelliJ because some tutorial said I needed to. But now I can't open my IntelliJ. Instead I get this error message:

[image: errormessage]

I looked up the error message and found out it has something to do with the vmoptions but I can't find out what I have to do to solve this.

This is what is in my vmoptions file:

idea64.exe.vmoptions :

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
```

Should I change something in this file or do I need to delete it? Anything else?

Comment: Try deleting the file from the Configuration directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory.

Comment: I cant find the file in this directory

Comment: Which file did you edit? The one in bin directory? Does it help if you reinstall from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html?

Comment: I have two vmoptions files in my bin folder in program files, should I delete one of them?

Comment: No, reinstall IDE to revert to the defaults.

Comment: I edited a file using the help menu in ide itself, but I dont know which file I edited

Comment: It edited the file in the Configuration directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory. Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085) for the location of the config directory on your system.

Comment: YES, it worked thanks. I'm just blind, it was indeed in the Configuration directory. I deleted the file and intelliJ works again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *.vmoptions are in your profile directory (not sure where that is in windows; should be some folder under your 'username' folder) you can safely delete it - ide will use the default one, and create a copy then you try to edit it thru the ide dialog.

If that fails I'd try reinstalling the ide

Comment: I am looking for a file in my user directory but I haven't found it

Comment: here's the location of the config directory C:\Users\JohnS\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2021.1 (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory) - change the version and username accordingly. these files are edited via ui dialog.